# Parsing a .txt file and writing to excel in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, header

I have a .txt file in the sample as below

```
 Name:      XYZ

Date of Service:    12/27/2018

Speaker ID:         10101
Visit Start:        06/07/2018
Visit End:          06/18/2018
Recipient:      
CHIEF COMPLAINT:
Liver discomfort.
```

I want to parse the .txt file and write to excel as

```
Name  Date of Service  Speaker ID ....
XYZ   12/27/2018       10101
```

I wrote the following  code

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

textfiles = Input.txt

for a in textfiles:
    f = open(textfile, 'r+')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        row_list.append(row.split(':'))
    column_list = zip(*row_list)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    i = 0 
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            worksheet.write(item, i, column[item])
        i+=1
    workbook.save(textfile + '.xls')
```

But im getting result as written in excel in a single column

```
Name
XYZ
Speaker ID
10101
...

CHIEF COMPLAINT
Liver discomfort
```

Even in Pandas i tried it gave me the same output. Can someone help me how to write the header in row and its corresponding data in col.

Thanks
Meera.

Full Input File

```
Patient Name:       XYZ

Date of Service:    12/27/2018

Speaker ID:     10101
Visit Start:        06/07/2018
Visit End:      06/18/2018
Recipient:      
CHIEF COMPLAINT:
Chest discomfort.

HISTORY OF PRESENT ILLNESS:
The patient is a 64-year-old Caucasian female with a past medical history which is remarkable for severe COPD as well as severe coronary artery disease.  She has a complex cardiac history including a coronary anomaly and coronary fistula with coronary bypass surgery with a left internal mammary artery graft to left anterior descending coronary artery in 2003.  Subsequently in 2007, for symptoms of a substernal chest heaviness, she was evaluated and wound up having a right coronary stent placed.  Her most recent angiography in 2012 demonstrated a patent left internal mammary artery to the LAD and patent other stents including the right coronary stent noted above.  She had sternal wires removed in 2012 because of sharp substernal chest discomfort.  She is a former smoker who quit many years ago prior to her coronary bypass graft surgery, but unfortunately has gone on to still have significant COPD.  Over the past several days to few weeks, she has had increasing amounts of shortness of breath, increasing amounts of substernal heaviness, mild to moderate in nature, coming on with exertion and going away with rest, not dissimilar from presentations in the past with coronary disease.  It should also note that she brought up the fact that she has "passed many stress tests with flying colors" and then went on to have coronary blockages.  She has been hospitalized now with an apparent exacerbation of COPD and this has not been completely cleared.  She denies any recent fevers or chills.  There has been no nausea, no vomiting, no abdominal pain, no focal neurologic complaints, no abnormal bleeding.

REVIEW OF SYSTEMS:
Complete review of systems in detail is as noted above, pertinent positives and negatives are as noted above, all other systems were reviewed and were negative.

PAST MEDICAL HISTORY:
Also remarkable for lifelong asthma with COPD, hypothyroidism, hypertension, and gastroesophageal reflux disease.

ALLERGIES:
Include,
1.  SULFA.
2.  PENICILLIN.
3.  CEPHALOSPORINS.

SOCIAL HISTORY:
As noted above.

FAMILY HISTORY:
Positive for "lots of heart disease."

PHYSICAL EXAMINATION:
VITAL SIGNS:  Remarkable most recently for a blood pressure of 128/60, a respiratory rate of 16, a pulse of 81, and a temperature of 36.7 degrees Centigrade.  Her saturation currently is 96% on room air.
HEENT:  Negative.
NECK:  Her jugular venous pressure is not elevated.  Her carotids are 2+ bilateral.  No bruits are heard.
LUNGS:  Have diffuse wheezing throughout both end-expiratory as well as inspiratory.  A few scattered rhonchi are noted bilaterally.  Mild kyphosis of her spine is noted.
CARDIOVASCULAR:  Cardiac auscultation demonstrates regular rate and rhythm, normal S1, normal S2.  No murmurs, gallops, or rubs are appreciated.
GASTROINTESTINAL:  Soft, nontender, with normal active bowel sounds.
EXTREMITIES:  Demonstrate no cyanosis, clubbing or edema.
NEUROLOGIC:  She is nonfocal and is able to move all extremities.
PSYCHIATRIC:  She is awake, alert and oriented x3 and cooperative.
SKIN:  Warm and dry.

DIAGNOSTIC DATA:
Her electrocardiogram shows sinus rhythm, incomplete right bundle-branch block, nonspecific anterior T-wave changes, and this is largely unchanged compared to previous tracings.

Her last echocardiogram, which was in 2006, demonstrated normal LV systolic function and her right atrium and right ventricle appeared at that time to be normal.

Her cardiac catheterization in 01/2012 showed the aforementioned patent LIMA bypass to the LAD.  There was a patent LAD stent.  There was a patent stent to the right posterior descending coronary artery.  There was an anomalous left coronary artery arising from the right coronary cusp, normal LV systolic function and mild mitral regurgitation.

Her chest x-ray directly reviewed by me, as was her previous EKG, showed clearcut changes associated with COPD, hyperinflation, no infiltrates.

IMPRESSION:
The patient had symptoms of chest tightness and heaviness when she presented with her catheterization for 2012 and at that time, all of her major coronary arteries were patent.  Her course here has been predominantly pulmonary.  Her laboratories include a BNP which is only 40.  Her one cardiac troponin was 0.02.  Her symptoms are unlikely to be coronary.  She had a nuclear stress test, which by her report a year ago this summer, appeared to be "normal."  We will check her echocardiogram for any interval change in LV systolic function, in particular for regional wall motion abnormalities.  If there are no regional wall motion abnormalities, I think she will be able to be discharged from a cardiac perspective, although her lungs are clearly still with significant finding of wheezing.  With regard to her coronary status, she is on atorvastatin 20 per day and this should be continued.  Blood pressure on steroid taper will need to be watched closely.

PLAN:
No Symptoms
```

As per the file PLAN will be the last heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = open('yourtextfile.txt').read()
#OR
text = ''' Name:      XYZ
       Date of Service:    12/27/2018
       Speaker ID:         10101
       Visit Start:        06/07/2018
       Visit End:          06/18/2018
       Recipient:
       CHIEF COMPLAINT:
       Liver discomfort.'''

rows = [x for x in text.split('\n') if x]
for n in range(len(rows)):
    if 'CHIEF COMPLAINT' in rows[n]:
        rows[n] = ''.join(rows[n:])
        del rows[n+1:]
        break
print(rows)
[' Name:      XYZ',
 'Date of Service:    12/27/2018',
 'Speaker ID:         10101',
 'Visit Start:        06/07/2018',
 'Visit End:          06/18/2018',
 'Recipient:      ',
 'CHIEF COMPLAINT:Liver discomfort.']

df = pd.DataFrame([{row.split(':')[0].strip(): row.split(':')[1].strip() for row in rows}])
print(df)
  Name Date of Service Speaker ID Visit Start   Visit End Recipient    CHIEF COMPLAINT
0  XYZ      12/27/2018      10101  06/07/2018  06/18/2018            Liver discomfort.
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . It is working if I give text = string as you have mentioned . But my input is a .txt file . I need to read the file and iterate .When i give 
'
text = ("C:/Users/Gayathri/Prathap/Test/1.txt")
'
im getting the same as in output excel

Comment: replace the line with `text = open('yourtextfile.txt').read()` and please mark the answer as correct answer if this helps you.

Comment: One more doubt , You have mentioned in If CHIEF COMPLAINT in rows[n] . But i have many rows after that . I just gave as a sample file . IF i try im getting IndexError: list index out of range when last line of code is executed  "df = pd.DataFrame([{row.split(':')[0].strip(): row.split(':')[1].strip() for row in rows}])" . I tried to get the max length of the whole file and assigned . Still getting the same error.  Can you please  help .

Comment: Based on the sample input I assumed that `CHIEF COMPLAINT:` is the last key in the file and `Liver discomfort.` is its value not followed by any other line. All lines have key/value in same line and if they are separated by new line, the logic needs to be changed in the code.  If you have more lines, could you please share a full text file.

Comment: HI Idar , Thanks for all the responses . I have edited the post to add the input file as you have mentioned.